# My computer won't use all usable RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, desktop-computer

I bought a gaming PC during last winter (https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883102333) and it was working very well the first couple months.

I'm not sure if it's when I wanted to start streaming on Twitch a bit, but my RAM started acting weird. Whenever I would use around 60% memory, the whole computer would start freezing and telling me that it doesn't have enough memory to run an application (For instance, Overwatch wouldnt launch without encounterring this error).

**So, the problem is: My computer has 16Go RAM, but won't use more than 60-65%.**

**What I've tried:**

- I tested each RAM module individually to see if there was one faulty, but they both seemed OK (PC detects it, and I can use the memory without having anything crash)
- I ran a memory test (https://hcidesign.com/memtest/), and used the maximum memory I could.
- I checked if my drivers were up to date (not sure if can have an impact)
- Ran virus/malware scan

**Additionnal information** : Sometimes, it will be worse, and by that I mean that I only have Google Chrome opened, and my computer will shut it down because it doesn't have enough memory (especially since the latest Chrome update). When I just remove / put the RAM back in its place, it will sometimes go back to the "usual" 60-65% RAM limit.

Anyone has an idea of what I can do to fix this problem?

I don't want to take it to the repairman just yet because I need my computer for my studies too (not just gaming!)

Comment: Prove it's a Windows, not hardware issue: Make a Linux Ubuntu LiveUSB with persistence https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent on your Windows PC. Boot from the Linux LiveUSB, open Firefox, go to https://www.google.com/chrome/ and install Chrome. Then, install Twitch from a Terminal Window w/ the 3 Ubuntu commands a la https://www.fossmint.com/gnome-twitch-watch-twitch-streams-on-linux - does it work? Then your PC's AOK!  PS: Your Windows will be untouched, because Linux runs from the LiveUSB, http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2928234/windows-half-installed-ram.html has more...

Comment: The "low on memory" (or "out of memory", or etc.) messages have nothing directly to do with RAM usage, but with running out of space for committed virtual memory.  The behavior you describe is very typical for a system without an adequate pagefile.

Comment: See these other questions and answers: https://superuser.com/questions/1027008 , https://superuser.com/questions/1199002/ , https://superuser.com/questions/1174229 . If you're not happy with those answers, please edit your Q to include screen caps of: 1) Task manager's "Details" tab with the "Memory (private working set)" column showing; 2) Task Manager's "Performance" tab's "memory" page; 3) Resource Monitor's "memory" tab (run ResMon from the link at the bottom of Task manager's  "Performance" tab) ; 4) RAMmap's "Use Counts" tab (RAMmap comes from sysinternals.com).

Comment: Er, rather, ask a new question, and include those things, and explain why you think the explanations in the linked answers aren't correct.

Comment: I will try the thing with virtual memory, I just have to wait for my computer to have the same problem. Thanks for the help guys, I'll keep you updated when I have anything new.